# In Expression Engine 4, live look preview is displaying A HREF links

Tags: ee4, livelook

Instead of a normal blue link, LIVE LOOK renders the link like this:
[url="http://www.geomagic.com" target="_blank"]Geomagic[/url]

I am using EE 4.1.3.

How can I prevent the live look preview from rendering the URL links within an article? I would like the links to display as normal "a href" links. I have WYGWAM installed and the {body} field is set to use the WYGWAM add-on. This display issue above also happens on non-WYGWAM fields in live look, too. I would like the links to just render as normal links.

Are there settings or defaults for live look?

Can we update the default CSS/JS live look uses to alter the URLs? I have used a method similar to this for "printer friendly" pages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my own question.

After figuring out that I needed to identify the WYGWAM field as an XHTML-formatted field, I used a simple add-on -- Typography-ee.

https://buzzingpixel.com/software/typographee

This worked:

```
{exp:typographee:parse text_format="xhtml"}
   {body}
{/exp:typographee:parse}
```

I use this just for my preview template.